# How do I download artifacts from GitHub during build?

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I need as a part of the build process to download contents from external github repository. I set up repository under "services" but I can not find a task which will download artifacts from that repo.

I use TFS 2017 on prem. My repository is already set to Git repo and I need to have one of build steps to pull data from yet another Git repo. How do i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Build for the same github repo

- #### If you want to download artifacts to your local path, you only need to use `copy files task` in your build definition.

  Get source: select Github and use github token to authoize. If you want CI build, set in Triggers Tab.

  Copy Files: set `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` as **Source Folder**, specify the file you want to download in **Contents**, set a local path as **Target Folder**.

  [image]
- #### If you want to download/publish artifacts to VSTS server or share folder, you can use `copy files task` and `publish build artifacts task` in you build defnition.

  Get source: select from github.

  Copy Files: set `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` as **Source Folder**, specify the file you want to download in **Contents**, set `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` as **Target Folder.**

  Publish Build Artifacts: set `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` as **Path to Publish**, select the type you want to publish.

**The way to connect github repo for TFS build:**

In TFS build definition -> Repository Tab -> select External Git -> click Manage to add an External Git Service Endpoint -> input your github repo URL, username and password -> OK -> Then select the endpoint as connection.

---

### Build for a git repo, and also need to download code from another github repo

You can use **Command Line** task to clone the github repo to your `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` folder.

#### Settings of command Line task:

Tool: `git`

Arguments: `clone https://github.com/username/repo`

[image]

Now the code of the github repo is cloned in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\repo`.

Comment: How do I set source folder to pull from external git repository? My repository (which is setup under "Repository" tab is NOT a source for this files. I want to pull files from OTHER GIT repository

Comment: I updated it in my answer, you can have a try. And it seems you are using the old out looking format of build definition, but the setting is similar (you can set in Repository Tab).

Comment: I updated my question with screenshot of what I have (TFS 2017 latest on prem build). I already have repository specified in my project as external GIT. It's not an issue. I need to pull data as one of the steps from OTHER git repo, not the one my project is build from.

Comment: OK, I give two situations and the details setting in my answer. You can have a try.